# Amazon Managed Blockchain - How do I SSH into network peer?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I SSH into Amazon Managed Blockchain (AMB) peer instance?

On my local machine with Hyperledger Fabric setup I can ssh into running docker container of this peer and check peer logs. I would like to do same with AMB. At least check peer logs.

There is also a "peer endpoint" in a following format: `nd-xxx.m-xxx.n-xxx.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:30003`, not sure, maybe it can it help me somehow?

Comment: What does "AMB" stand for? Clearly I can't answer your question, but if you are a bit more explicit about what you need, and perhaps adding appropriate tags, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @Tim https://aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this?